# TabControl contents disappears when I execute the program

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have Form contains many controls including TabControl.

The problem occurs when I execute the program, the contents of the tabPage disappear.

The following are pictures of the Form before and after the Execute and the source code
before:

i.stack.imgur.com/Sd0na.jpg

after :

i.stack.imgur.com/y5pYy.jpg

Source Code: http://www.mediafire.com/?8d19lx1h2wwgl3m

Please help

Comment: You might get better help if you posted to the Telerik forums.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say for sure as with 'Telerik.WinControls' resource I can't run the code.

That said it looks to be a problem with how you are loading the Main Form. I presume the issue being you can see the controls in the designer in visual studio, but not when the code is run. To resolve this remove the `Main_Load` method and place its contents in the default `Main` constructor like so in the `Main.cs` file.

```
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Create Directory
        sFunctions.CreateDirectory("Pictures");

        ClassConnections conn = new ClassConnections();
        conn.setConnection(
          AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Database\\",
          "MasterFile.mdb",
          "lib2006");

        publicMainForm = this;
    }
```

Then remove the line

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Main_Load);
```

From the `Main.Designer.cs` file

Comment: thanks bro, i do that But the problem still exists
http://i.stack.imgur.com/y5pYy.jpg

Comment: Hmm, like I say, without the control lib I can't run the sample. Will have another look though...